# How can I write the python import statements, such that the file works from both inside and outside its package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

Here's a file structure I'm working with:

```
package_example/
  main.py
  the_package/
    __init__.py
    pkg_file_1.py
    pkg_file_2.py
```

Here are the files:

```py
# main.py
from the_package.pkg_file_1 import foo_1


def main():
    foo_1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# pkg_file_1.py
from the_package import pkg_file_2


def foo_1():
    print("this is the second version, foo_1")
    pkg_file_2.foo_2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_1()
```

```py
# pkg_file_2.py

def foo_2():
    print("this is foo_2")
```

If I run `main.py`, everything works fine.

But if I run `pkg_file_1.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_package/pkg_file_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from the_package import pkg_file_2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'the_package'
```

Obviously in this simplified example, it doesn't matter, since `main.py` and `pkg_file_1.py` run the same code.

But practically, I have test scripts baked into my package structure, so I can test the code in my new environment and data. But I'm scratching my head on how I'm supposed write import statements such that I don't get a `ModuleNotFoundError` from both inside or outside the package.

Edit: From pavel's suggest I tried changing `pkg_file_1.py` to:

```py
from ..the_package import pkg_file_2


def foo_1():
    print("this is the second version, foo_1")
    pkg_file_2.foo_2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_1()
```

But running that same file gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_package/pkg_file_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..the_package import pkg_file_2
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: How about `from ..the_package import pkg_file_2` since it's one level up?

Comment: The way PyCharm and (i believe VSCode as well) work around is by adding root directory of a project to Pythonpath in which case your imports would work just fine.

Comment: @pavel see edit.

Comment: Actually just one dot in front. My typo

Comment: @pavel Is there a Pythonic way to achieve that? Because if I add it with sys.path I get warnings about having import statements below non-import code.

Comment: @pavel Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_package/pkg_file_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .the_package import pkg_file_2
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: This has been covered a zillion times on stack overflow. You can't run submodules directly as scripts when using relative imports. The duplicate, which is the first search result for the error message you got (`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`) describes why in extensive detail, and shows the alternative approach using `python -m pkg.submodule`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why we need relative import.

```py
# pkg_file_1.py
from . import pkg_file_2
...
```

How to run `main.py` and `pkg_file1.py` from `package_example` dir:

```sh
python3 main.py
python3 -m the_package.pkg_file1
```